# Add 2 sparlines in a google sheet to create a new sparkline

Tags: google-sheets, sparklines

I have 2 sparklines. Both are created based on historical share prices of stocks from a year ago to today.
I want to create a new sparkline that is the sum of these 2 charts. Is this possible given that the have the same number of data points i.e 365.
e.g

```
=SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily"),{"charttype","line";"linewidth",1;"color","#5f88cc"})
=SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily"),{"charttype","line";"linewidth",1;"color","#5f88cc"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join them as a single array and then use query to add them:

```
=SPARKLINE(
  QUERY(
    {
      GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily"),
      GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily")
    },
    "select Col1, Col2+Col4",
    1
  )
)
```

### Rundown

We first join the two arrays. To do so we use the array syntax `{A,B}` to join them row by row, making a 4 column array:

```
={
  GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily"),
  GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily")
}
```

Now we can apply a query to get the values we want:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily"),
    GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily")
  },
  "select Col1, Col2+Col4",
  1
)
```

The query is making 2 rows:

1. The date column. Since it should be the same for both, no need to change anything
2. The sum of the 2 `Close` columns (2 and 4)

After that we can simply wrap everything to the `SPARKLINE` function, and we have our final result.

If you don't like having the whitespace characters, you can remove them without any problem.

### Reference

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- [QUERY function (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)